# ESLint: constructors and enum values are reported as unused but they are used in app.ts

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have a NodeJS project with Express and TypeScript.

Some of the classes/enums usied in the project are reported by ESLint as unused althought they are used in the project's entrypoint file (app.ts in my case).

For instance,  I have a class defined in `handler/RequestHandler.ts` as follows:

```
export class RequestHandler {
    constructor (private readonly manager: Manager) {}
    ...
}
```

The in the `app.ts` it is used like this:

```
 import { RequestHandler } from './handler/RequestHandler'
 //....
 const handler = new RequestHandler(manager)
```

But when I run linter I get:

```
/path-to-my-project-root/src/handler/RequestHandler.ts
  5:2  error  Useless constructor  no-useless-constructor
```

I thought it ignores `app.ts` but if I break linter rules for `app.ts` (for instance by adding unneeded spaces) it would report it.

The same happens with enumeration values.

**Question:** How to make ESLint see constructor/enum usages in the app.ts file?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the project FAQ which answers your question:
https://typescript-eslint.io/docs/linting/troubleshooting#i-am-using-a-rule-from-eslint-core-and-it-doesnt-work-correctly-with-typescript-code

Specifically, you're using the wrong lint rule.
https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-useless-constructor/